# Was a comment complaining about sexism deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

In [Are there any jobs in the programming field that don't require you to sit at a desk all day?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/115115/are-there-any-jobs-in-the-programming-field-that-dont-require-you-to-sit-at-a-d/115127#115127),

one user said in comments

> (2 upvotes) +1 this is a good suggestion... I forgot to mention that.
>   Plus, you didn't mention the main perk... young impressionable
>   (female) undergrads. :P – AJC 9 hours ago

and another was

> (7 upvotes) Although in my experience females seem to account for about 10 % of
>   class size, add impressionable & attractive and you will soon find
>   there isnt much of a pool there ! – NWS 7 hours ago

Further down in the comments, someone has said

> (1 upvote, by me) @AJC, NWS, you're f-ing scum. So is everyone who voted that up. (And
>   f- the moderators who deleted my comment but not the above.) – Joe
>   Wreschnig 1 hour ago

Did a moderator delete a comment complaining about sexism without deleting the sexist comments? Or was the comment automatically deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire comment chain was purged and the post locked. I literally completed this 30 seconds ago: looks like you caught it mid-purge.

Comment: No, Joe's comment complaining about sexism was deleted more than one hour ago, because the complaint about it being deleted was more than one hour ago.

Comment: But thanks for deleting all the comments.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I can see when comments were deleted and by whom: every comment was deleted by me 7 minutes ago, including the ones by Joe. I'm guessing you and he didn't see it because the comment chain was collapsed due to too many comments being posted.

Comment: Ok. Out of curiosity, how many upvotes did Joe's comment that he thought was deleted get?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm None. There were three comments: the initial one and two identical ones about mods "deleting" the comments. The IDs for all the comments are right next to each other (210379, 210380, 210381), and the timestamps were less than 3 minutes apart: looks like it was just user confusion.

Comment: Thanks for that, though I'm rather sad it didn't get upvoted.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig I assure you, your comments were not deleted until I purged the entire lot. There is no auto-deletion for using expletives, but as an aside, [using them is not acceptable here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233): please try to use more constructive language in the future. If something is offensive, flag it for moderator attention so we can deal with it.

Comment: @Mark: Maybe you need to familiarize yourself with how Stack Exchange's flags work; a comment that contains particular words and gets an offensive flag is deleted without human moderators involved. I've run across this before when I linked to a well-known presentation in the game development community called "Typical C++ bullshit" using its title. (And no. That encouragement of sexual predation was left unchallenged for half a day and received seven upvotes is bad enough, I am not just going to "flag and move on" and wait for someone else to maybe deal with it.)

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Moderators can see exactly when and how comments are deleted: when Community deletes a comment due to an offensive flag (or any other reason), we know about it because our dashboard tells us. Your comments were not deleted by Community, they were deleted by me at the same time as every other comment. Keep in mind the time difference between your first comment and the comment where you blasted the moderators was *less than three minutes*: the only offensive flags in that time period was on the original comment by AJC.

Comment: @Mark: Then perhaps the site was malfunctioning, because I did not delete my comments, yet they disappeared. I and other people I know looking at the thread only ever saw one of my comments at a time; we all know how to use SO to expand comment threads. Presumably Andrew also saw only my most recent comment or he would've mentioned the earlier ones. Perhaps there's yet another counter in the system for "offensive" comments.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Given the short amount of time between your first comment and your comments about the moderators deleting your comments, I humbly suggest what you saw at the time was a cached page. They were there when I came upon them two hours later.